# Nebula ospackage does not respect dirMode

Tags: gradle, rpm, netflix-nebula-plugins

I have the following buildscript and I need to force directory permissions and create an empty directory. I found on many places that the following code should work, but it does not. Any hints whats wrong?

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:4.8.0'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'nebula.ospackage'

ospackage {
    def userName = 'myapp'
    def userRoot = 'root'
    preInstall "id -u ${userName} &>/dev/null || useradd ${userName}"

    packageName = "myapp"
    version = project.version
    release = '40'
    arch = NOARCH
    os = LINUX

    user = userRoot
    permissionGroup = userName

    directory('/opt/myapp/aaa', 0750) //directory not created
    from("src/config") {
        into('/opt/myapp/etc')
        dirMode 0750 // directory in RPM has drwxr-xr-x
    }

    requires("shadow-utils", "4.1.5.1", 0x04|0x08)
}

build.dependsOn(buildRpm)
```

After some more investigation this seems to be a bug, I have created an [issue in Nebula GitHub](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/279).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the `directory()` construct does not work in the `ospackage` closure. You'll have to add an `Rpm` type closure to do this.

See the [Rpm section of the docs](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/RPM-Plugin) and [this ticket](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/issues/183).

```
apply plugin: 'nebula.rpm'

task fooRpm(type: Rpm) {
    directory('/opt/myapp/aaa', 0750)
}
```

If you want a Debian package, apply the same but in a [block of type:Deb](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/wiki/Deb-Plugin).